# コメント削除したら記事自体が削除される

Tags: php, cakephp

やりたいこととしてはコメント削除したら
その記事の詳細ページにredirectしたい。

しかし現状、コメントを削除すると
記事自体も削除され、トップページにredirectしてしまう・・・
アドバイス宜しくお願い致します。

【CommentsController】

```
<?php

class CommentsController extends AppController {
    public $helpers = array('Html', 'Form');



    public function add(){
        if ($this->request->is('post')){
            if ($this->Comment->save($this->request->data)){
                $this->Session->setFlash('Success!');
                $this->redirect(array('controller'=>'posts','action'=>'view',$this->data['Comment']['post_id']));
            } else {
                $this->Session->setFlash('failed!');
            }
        }
    }

    public function delete($id){
        if ($this->request->is('get')){
            throw new MethodNotAllowedException();
        }
        if ($this->Comment->delete($id)){
            $this->Session->setFlash('Deleted!');
            $this->redirect(array('controller'=>'posts','action'=>'view',$this->data['Comment']['post_id']));
        }
        //$this->redirect(array('controller'=>'posts', 'action'=>'index'));
    }
}


?>
```

【view.ctp】

```
<h2><?php echo h($post['Post']['title']); ?></h2>

<p><?php echo h($post['Post']['body']); ?></p>

<h2>Comments<h2/>
<ul>
<?php foreach ($post['Comment'] as $comment): ?>
<li>
<?php echo h($comment['body']) ?> by <?php echo h($comment['commenter']); ?>
<?php
    echo $this->Form->postLink('削除', array('action'=>'delete', $post['Post']['id']),array('confirm'=>'sure?'));
?>
</li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>


<h2>Add Comment</h2>

<?php
echo $this->Form->create('Comment', array('action'=>'add'));
echo $this->Form->input('commenter');
echo $this->Form->input('body', array('rows'=>3));
echo $this->Form->input('Comment.post_id', array('type'=>'hidden', 'value'=>$post['Post']['id']));
echo $this->Form->end('post comment');



?>
```

Answer (score 1):

view.ctpの

```
echo $this->Form->postLink('削除', array('action'=>'delete', $post['Post']['id']),array('confirm'=>'sure?'));
```

これは完全にPost削除用のコードになっています。まずコントローラー名が指定されていないので現在実行中の`PostsController`と解釈されます。それから渡しているIDもPostのものです。

なので以下のように修正する必要があります

```
echo $this->Form->postLink('削除', array('controller'=>'comments','action'=>'delete', $comment['id']),array('confirm'=>'sure?'));
```

Comment: すみません。やっと理解しました・・・
因みにコメント削除が完了すると【Warning (2): Invalid argument supplied for foreach() [APP/View/Posts/view.ctp, line 7]】のエラーメッセージが表示されるのですが、これはなんなのでしょうか？

Comment: @DaikiYamada 恐らくコメントが存在しないなどの理由で`$post['Comment']`の値が未設定とか`null`とかなんだと思います。foreachの外側にif文を入れて`isset($post['Comment'])`等で分岐し、コメントが無い場合の表示をしてやる必要があるかと。`print_r`の出力などを見ないと何とも言えませんが。

Comment: @DaikiYamada 本回答で解決した場合には回答の承認をよろしくお願いします。http://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers